# как исправить ошибку Syntax error or access violation при миграции таблицы в Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, миграция

При вводе команды php artisan migrate выходит такая ошибка

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `permissions` add unique `permissions_name_guard_name_unique`(`name`, `guard_name`))
```

Answer (score 0):

Измените параметр defaultStringLegth .  Сделать это возможно, вызвав метод Schema::defaultStringLength внутри AppServiceProvider. Для этого открываем файл:
defaultStringLegth равным 191

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```